# Problems installing Gitorious on Debian 6.0.4

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, debian-squeeze, gem, git

i am trying to install Gitorious on latest Debian 6.0.4 but i am running into some problems and hope there is somebody out here who might be able to help.

I followed this article: http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/DebianSqueezeInstallation
I installed the latest versions of all 3rd party applications like Ruby-Enterprise, Sphinx and ActiveMQ.

Could it have to do with some incompatible versions or "gems" ?

Here is the error when i try to start the daemon:

```
/etc/init.d/git-daemon start
Starting git-daemon:
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/lib/ultrasphinx/ultrasphinx.rb:201: private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/lib/ultrasphinx.rb:15 from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/init.rb:2:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/environment.rb:24
from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /var/www/gitorious/script/git-daemon:11 failure
```

Here is the problem when trying to start sphinx:

```
/etc/init.d/git-ultrasphinx start
(in /var/www/gitorious)
rake aborted!
private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the list of gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.1)
activemessaging (0.7.1)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1, 2.3.8)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.1, 2.3.8)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.0.6)
addressable (2.2.6)
arel (3.0.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
capillary (1.0.0)
capybara (1.0.1)
childprocess (0.2.1)
chronic (0.3.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
echoe (4.3.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
exception_notification (1.0.20090728)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.9)
gemcutter (0.6.1)
geoip (0.8.9)
hike (1.2.1)
hodel_3000_compliant_logger (0.1.0)
hoe (2.8.0)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.1)
json (1.6.5, 1.5.4)
json_pure (1.5.0)
launchy (2.0.5)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
mocha (0.9.10)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
oauth (0.4.4)
paperclip (2.2.9.2)
passenger (3.0.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
proxymachine (1.2.4)
rack (1.4.1, 1.0.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.8.7)
rdiscount (1.3.1.1)
rdoc (3.12)
redis (2.2.0)
redis-namespace (0.7.0)
resque (1.9.8)
revo-ssl_requirement (1.1.0)
riddle (1.2.2)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-net-ldap (0.0.4)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.4.0)
shoulda (2.9.2)
sinatra (1.0)
sprockets (2.1.2)
state_machine (0.9.4)
stomp (1.1)
SystemTimer (1.2.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tuxml (0.0.1)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
validates_url_format_of (0.1.1)
vegas (0.1.8)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

I really appreciate any help to solve the problem or point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance!
Thomas